# Managed secret to environment in Kubernetes deployment manifest

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, amazon-kms

Want to move secrets to AWS KMS and directly refer it from env of manifest file or do same with HashiCorp Vault. Tried finding solutions but all add it to a file and not directly to environment in manifest.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of the process of doing it using AWS specifically, but Kubernetes is pretty straightfoward on how to [Use Secrets as Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables), good luck!

Comment: @willrof Thanks, There was requirement to use something other than using kubernetes secret but we settled for kubernetes secret for now as couldn't find other solution that could help us in this case.